# 3 Dimensional Geometry

Tags: geometry, 3d

Greedy Geoff sawed off a corner of a brick shaped block of Christmas cake, exposing a triangular fresh face of moist rich delicious gateau. He placed the tetrahedral fragment on the table, with its fresh face downwards. He mused through a port laden haze that it looked very stable, just like a mountain in fact, with its summit above a point inside its (not necessarily equilateral) triangular footprint $ABC$. He decided to decorate it, and took a UKMT pennant flying from a toothpick, and stuck it at the summit, with the flagpole perfectly vertical. Of course, the port was still at work and he is a bit clumsy, so he jammed the toothpick right through the cake, stabbing it into the tablecloth at a point $X$. Show that the circles $ABX$, $BCX$ and $CAX$ all have the same radius.

Comment: I thought gato meant cat.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_orthoscheme

Comment: Damn it, contest problem: http://www.mathcomp.leeds.ac.uk/

Comment: Alright, evidently a public contest problem from 2005: see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6629/another-contest-problem

Comment: Could you please make the title a little more descriptive?

Comment: But of course the OP should say (if he knows) "contest problem from 2005".  Then Will (and others, like me) won't get all excited about it's appropriateness for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Call summit vertex $S$.

Now, put the piece of cake back where it came from --use the toothpick to hold it in place-- and let's assume that vertex $A$ lies along the vertical edge of the cake. Take the knife and make a vertical cut along $SA$ that slices perpendicularly through $BC$ at, say, $F$. The plane of the cut, being perpendicular to a line in face $ABC$, is necessarily perpendicular to face $ABC$ itself; the cut must have split the toothpick. Therefore, the projection into face $ABC$ of segment $SA$ --together with the projection of $SF$-- forms an *altitude* of $\triangle ABC$. The same is true of similar cuts through $SB$ and $SC$: the foot of the toothpick lies on all three altitudes, so that $X$ must be the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$.

From here, proof is fairly straightforward using the plane geometry of $\triangle ABC$: With $X$ the common point on altitudes dropped from $A$, $B$, and $C$, one can show (for instance) that $\angle BXC = 180^\circ-\angle BAC$. Consequently, by the Law of Sines in $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle XBC$,

$$\text{circumdiameter of } \triangle ABC = \frac{|BC|}{\sin\angle BAC} = \frac{|BC|}{\sin\angle BXC} = \text{circumdiameter of } \triangle XBC$$

Thus, not only are the circumcircles of $\triangle XBC$, $\triangle XCA$, and $\triangle XAB$ congruent to each other, they're congruent to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ itself.